# How to check if Chartboost interstitial is loaded?

Tags: unity-game-engine, chartboost

For somehow I don't get Chartboost interstitial loaded every time, asked them and as most answers:"no more of the interstitials available at the time you're testing in the network satisfy the conditions......". So now I use revmob also. The question I have: how to check if Chartboost is preloaded? my code so far:

```
if(Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.Default))
{
        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.Default);
}else {
        revmob.ShowFullscreen();
}
```

I only receive revmob interstitials. Is my checking condition ok? Saw something about delegates but I am not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you checking condition is OK.

For using delegates read this [Chartboost Documentation](https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/unity-3) on delegates in Unity3D. I think it has a pretty good explanation on how to implement delegate methods. Also I will **HIGHLY** recommend that you do implement these delegate methods as they will help you not only with displaying ad status logs but also identifying problems regarding Ad display.

EDIT for future reference:

For example:

Implementing `Chartboost.didCacheInterstitial` and `Chartboost.didFailToLoadInterstitial` delegates will tell you if and when an interstitial ad was loaded or failed. The fail delegate(s) also sends an error as parameter so you would know why the cache was failed.

If the delegates are not being called then there is an issue with your chartboost SDK integration in your project inside unity. In that case try re-importing the chartboost sdk and check you chartboost dashboard for issues. One of the most common issues >> make sure that there is an active ad campaign linked to your in chartboost dashboard. To setup an ad campaign follow: [Start a Publishing Campaign](https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/articles/204930539)